# Select All departments which has employeeId is null and is not null?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select All the departments which has null values of `employeeId` and not null values of `employeeId`?

Department

```
id       employeeID
 1           1
 1           null
 2           2
 3           null
```

The result should be department id - 1

Comment: Shouldn't department ID 3 be in the results?

Comment: department id 3 should not be in the result, since it does not match is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      id
from        department
group by    id
having      count(employeeId) between 1 and count(*)-1
```

---

`count(employeeId)` counts non-NULL employeeId

- If it is > 0 it means we have at least one NOT NULL value.
- If it is < count(*) it means we have at least one NULL value.

Comment: Even better than my answer! Accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

So you want department id's for which there are some null and some non-null employeeid's?

You can use GROUP BY to reduce the set of rows for each department id.

Then filter the groups with `HAVING` such that there's a nonzero number of entries in the group with NULL employeeid, and also a nonzero number of entries in the group with non-NULL employeeid.

```
SELECT id
FROM Department
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN employeeID IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 0 
  AND  COUNT(CASE WHEN employeeID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, employeeID from tablename GROUP BY id, employeeID;
```

This will `GROUP BY id, employeeID` and return you all the records.

Answer (score 0):

I do not about department table structure.

You can try below query.

For Not null values of employee id

```
      SELECT id 
        FROM tablename 
       WHERE employeeID is not null 
    GROUP BY employeeID 
   INTERSECT
      SELECT id 
       FROM tablename 
      WHERE employeeID is null 
   GROUP BY employeeID
```

You can try this solution.

Comment: yes using two queries you can find it. but I need it within a query

Comment: You can use union between these two query and give alias in one of the tables. that would help.

Comment: `UNION` wont help you to achieve what is asked in the question

Answer (score 0):

Simply go with `EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.id
FROM TAB T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TAB T1 WHERE T.id = T1.id AND T1.employeeID IS NULL)
AND EXISTS  (SELECT 1 FROM TAB T1 WHERE T.id = T1.id AND T1.employeeID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Intersect will do the trick

```
select * from (
SELECT id from Department WHERE employeeID is not null
INTERSECT
SELECT id from Department WHERE employeeID is null
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to return id's where the number of employeeID's are greater than 0 and also less than the total number of that id rows.

```
select id
from department
group by id
having count(employeeID) > 0
   and count(employeeID) < count(*)
```

(`count(employeeID)` counts non-null rows. `count(*)` counts all rows.)

Answer (score 0):

### You can try this:

```
select id, employeeId from department order by id;
```